# Classify all the fields with abelian absolute Galois group

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, absolute-galois-group

I'm wondering if anyone has classified all the fields $K$ such that $Gal(\bar{K}/K)$ is abelian?

The only examples I'm aware of are: finite fields, the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and $k((T))$ where $k$ is any algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. (One might also add any algebraically closed field as an example not listed above...)

Is there any other example of such fields?

An possibly easier question would be: can one apriori prove that $Gal(\bar{K}/K)$ is procyclic as suggested by the examples above?

Comment: The real numbers can be replaced by real closed fields. Finite fields can be replaced by algebraic extensions of finite fields. Do you know all the closed subgroups of the profinite integers $\widehat{\mathbf Z}$?

Comment: The finite fields can be replaced by [quasi-finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-finite_field).

Comment: Exercise 3, Chapter 8, Lang's "Algebra":  $K$ = a maximal subfield of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ not containing $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Ah, thanks to all of your comments. So it seems to me that all the examples listed above have absolute galois group either $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2$?

Comment: Consider the iterated formal power series field $K=k((T_1))((T_2))\cdots((T_n))$ with $k$ an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and you'll get a field $K$ with $Gal(\overline{K}/K)=\widehat{\mathbb Z}^n$.

Comment: On the other hand, $\widehat{\mathbb Z}\times \mathbb Z/2$ is not an absolute Galois group, I believe (because the modified supercommutativity rule has to hold in the Galois cohomology with constant coefficients $\mathbb Z/2$).

Comment: @LeonidPositselski Thanks to your comment, so procyclicity is also wrong. Good to know, thanks again.

Comment: My argument shows that, denoting the $p$-adic integers by $\mathbb Z_p$, the group $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z/2$ is not an absolute Galois group.  Still I don't know whether $\mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z/2$ can be an absolute Galois group for odd $p$.

Comment: @LeonidPositselski  $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ cannot be the absolute Galois group of a field, for any prime $p$. More generally, the normalizer of an involution in an absolute Galois group of a field is the group of order 2 generated by this involution.  See Proposition 19.4.3 in: I. Efrat, Valuations, Orderings, and Milnor K-Theory, AMS 2006.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Geyer in [Unendliche algebraische Zahlkörper, über denen jede Gleichung auflösbar von beschränkter Stufe ist](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(69)90050-X), Satz 1.13 and the paragraph after that, gives a full characterization of which abelian profinite groups occur as absolute Galois groups: They are either $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ or $\prod_p\mathbb{Z}_p^{c(p)}$ for some cardinal numbers $c(p)$.

Side remark: For *algebraic* extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, abelian absolute Galois groups are in fact procyclic, see Satz 2.3 in the same paper.

Comment: Note: these are exactly $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ and all torsion-free profinite abelian groups.