# Fields such that every finite Galois extension is solvable

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, profinite-groups

What are the fields such that every finite Galois extension is solvable?

We have algebraically closed fields, real closed fields, p-adic fields. Anything else?

A more pointed question after comments:

> Which non-abelian absolute Galois groups have only solvable finite
> quotients?

Comment: Finite fields. . . . .

Comment: Separably closed fields, finite fields, [quasi-finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-finite_field),... I doubt there is any reasonable classification.

Comment: [Related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262108/classify-all-the-fields-with-abelian-absolute-galois-group) for fields with *abelian* absolute Galois groups - no complete answer, but some hopefully helpful references.

Comment: Isn't the "more pointed" question just a restatement? (apart from excluding abelian cases).

Comment: It is possible for different fields to have the same absolute Galois group, I think it emphasizes the groups more clearly

Comment: If you only consider the group, it's plainly a question about profinite groups and the answer is "prosolvable groups", by definition (which more properly should be called "pro-(finite solvable)"). This, in a sense, makes the question disappointing: the interest is when fields are of some interest.

Comment: If one takes a $p$-Sylow in the absolute Galois group of $\mathbf{Q}$, it seems it corresponds to an extension whose absolute Galois group is pro-$p$. These groups are not solvable, see https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2015.05.017

Comment: Sorry I meant that there should be at least one field but we don't care if there is a lot of different fields realizing the same profinite group

Comment: As YCor says, the question could be rephrased as asking which prosolvable groups occur as absolute Galois groups. Koenigsmann (Solvable absolute Galois groups are metabelian, Invent. Math. 144, 2001) classified *solvable* absolute groups, but I don't think one has a complete answer to the prosolvable version.

Comment: OK. Actually, in the abelian case, the question which profinite *abelian* groups occur as absolute Galois groups is fully answered in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262108/): namely the cyclic group of order 2 and all torsion-free ones (which are classified: possibly infinite products of $p$-adics groups for primes $p$ allowing arbitrary multiplicities). However this says little about the classification of fields with this property.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, which such groups occur as absolute Galois groups and how the fields with these absolute Galois groups look like are two different questions. Note though that at least for the abelian case the work of Koenigsmann (on solvable absolute Galois groups) does give at least some information on these fields: Unless the group is projective, the field is either formally real or admits a nontrivial henselian valuation.