# Maximal abelian subgroups of absolute Galois group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

For both local and global fields, we have a good handle on the abelianization of the absolute Galois group of $K$. Essentially this allows us to "understand" all maps from $G_K$ to abelian groups.

Reversing arrows: If we want to understand maps $A\to G_K$ for abelian groups $A$, then we would need to know the maximal abelian subgroups of $G_K$. My question is if we know a good description of these groups (in either the global or local setting).

Comment: I see no reason why "the" maximal abelian subgroup should exist. However, for abelian subgroups this question here is relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/q/262108/50351

Comment: @ArnoFehm you are of course right, added in the plural, thanks!

Comment: Are there any such subgroups which are not (pro)cyclic?

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Apparently the answer to my question is no (at least if you consider closed subgroups, but a closure of an abelian subgroup would be abelian), see the final remark [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/352952/30186).

Comment: Each element of the Galois group generates an abelian subgroup. This alone lets me think there is no good answer to your question.

Comment: Since the maximal abelian subgroups are all procyclic, they are equivalent to the centralizers of elements. But there are lots of isomorphism classes of procyclic groups. What are the isomorphism classes for the Galois group of $\mathbb Q_p$? Some are $\hat{\mathbb Z}$. Are any $\mathbb Z_p$? I doubt there are any more exotic than those two possibilities. Deciding between those two possibilities is interesting. I think the answer is that they are all $\hat{\mathbb Z}$.