# Elementary abelian 2-subgroups of $\mathrm{Aut}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ (with and without choice)

Tags: axiom-of-choice, absolute-galois-group, involutions, conjugacy-classes

Consider the absolute Galois group $G_{\mathbb{Q}} := \mathrm{Aut}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$.

As I understand it, the only torsion elements have order $2$ (by Artin-Schreier), and they are all conjugate.

My questions concern the structure of this conjugacy class.

- What is the subgroup generated by all involutions ?
- How do the (largest) elementary abelian $2$-subgroups of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$
  look like ?

If we do not accept the Axiom of Choice, does the Artin-Schreier result still apply, as well as the answers on the aforementioned questions ? (In this case, I define $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ as the usual countable algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ inside $\mathbb{C}$.)

Comment: The subgroup generated by all involutions is the Galois group of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ over the maximal totally real extension of $\mathbb Q$ as this is the fixed field of all the complex conjugations.

Comment: Will Sawin answers the first question, and the structure of that subgroup is known (a result by Fried-Haran-Völklein). The abelian subgroups are also known, in particular every elementary 2-abelian subgroup is in fact cyclic (this I think is an older result by Geyer), see this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/352952/50351

Comment: @ArnoFehm: so they are finite of size 2 ?

Comment: @ArnoFehm: does Geyer use Choice to obtain that result ?